# ResponsiveVoice.js not working right with Phonegap compiler

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

Why isn't the TTS working when the webapp is compiled into an android app with phonegap?

I'm trying to get TTS working on my android app using ResponsiveVoice.js and compiled through phonegap (https://build.phonegap.com/apps/2204237/builds)

In the browser on tested phones and desktops it works fine, but once it's compiled and turned into an apk it stops working.

I'm using basic jQuery calls to envoke ResponsiveVoice.js when clicking the responding button.

Button:

```
<section>
    <a rel="external" href="#" id="zero" type="button" value="Play">&#xF011</a>
        <span>0</span>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
zero.onclick = function() {
    responsiveVoice.speak('Zero' + ' ' + $('#dropdown').val()  + ' ' + $('#name').val());
};
```

Full Code: https://github.com/hakarune/reading-pounds

Testing Page: https://rawgit.com/hakarune/reading-pounds/master/index.html

Is there a better method to go about this? I Stumbled on ResponsiveVoice.js and it was so easy to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to debug your app you'll see this message:

> RV: Voice synthesis not supported

It's populated by ResponsiveVoice, because speechSynthesis is not defined in Android

Here you can see it's supported in Chrome for Android, but not in Android Browser, which is the one used on Cordova Apps.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-synthesis

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, i didn't catch that when i checked the catlog. So there's no way to use RV, that's a shame. Thanks for the help. Guess I'm back too the drawing board on the speech. Thanks again.

Comment: There are multiple plugins for text to speech https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cordova%20tts&page=1&ranking=optimal https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechSynthesisPlugin

Comment: My problem is that sometime I receive the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined" and sometime it works. I suppose that responsiveVoice calls SpeechSynthesisUtterance under specific conditions that I don't understand...